# What does state "I" mean in htop?

Tags: linux, htop

I have recently observed an undocumented state "I" displayed in `htop` output.
[image: screenshot]
The default help message doesn't disclose any information about this hidden state.
[image]
Given all processes that hold this state are kernel processes(threads), there might be reasons that the "I" state is not documented in the default help message. However, I'm still curious what the "I" means and whether there are more special states for kernel threads. Any suggestions?